# Using Axioms of Probability to solve inequality

Tags: probability, functions, axioms

Suppose that $A,B$ and $C$ are events, show that:

A) $P(A \cup B \cup C) \leq P(A) +P(B) +P(C)$.

Hint: $P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) +P(B \setminus A) +P(C \setminus (A \cup B))$.

B) Formulate and prove a version of  for $n$ events rather than $3$.

Comment: The hint practically gives it away.  Tell me... how does $P(B\setminus A)$ compare to $P(B)$?  Is it always at least as big?  always at least as small?  or equal?

Comment: i know its smaller but it says start by showing **P(A∪B∪C) = P(A) +P(B|A) +P(C\(A∪B))**. So i have to find a way to get **P(A∪B∪C) = P(A) +P(B\A) +P(C\(A∪B))** in the first place

Comment: Note that $A\cup B\cup C = A\cup (B\setminus A) \cup (C\setminus (A\cup B))$.  This step should be easy to prove by element chasing.  Next, notice that $A, (B\setminus A),$ and $(C\setminus (A\cup B))$ are all mutually exclusive (i.e. their intersection is empty).  What does that tell you about their respective probabilities?

Comment: i think it get it but about about for n events?

Comment: Use induction, noting that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i = A_{n+1}\cup\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$

Comment: @JMoravitz: And in fact, this is probably easier than doing the $n=3$ case directly.

Comment: Also, I will point out that you have a pretty major typo which could be causing you some confusion.  The final term should read $P(C\color{red}{\setminus}(A\cup B))$

Comment: just noticed it too . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\sigma$-field (or Venn diagram) ${\cal F}$  generated by the sets $A$, $B$, $C$. It contains $8$ elements $F_i$ (some of them may be empty). Each $F_i$  that occurs in $A\cup B\cup C$ is counted at least once on the right hand side of the stated inequality.